# Remove Admin sidebar link

Tags: admin, admin-menu, links

I have a taxonomy link in my admin sidebar i'd like removed from view.

Only in the sidebar though, i will still be using the function in the post view, so if that creates problems a simple simple CSS trick will do. Just need it gone from the sidebar as it's unnecessary clutter.

The current link looks like:

http://domain.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=featured&post_type=movies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function remove_featured_tax_menu()
{
    remove_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=movies',
        'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=featured&amp;post_type=movies'
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_featured_tax_menu' );
```